# Как в SearchView добавить голосовой поиск?

Tags: android, searchview, голосовой-поиск

В Toolbar разместил сам виджет поиска

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
  >

  <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/search_view"
  android:layout_gravity="right"
  app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
  app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"/>


  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Реализуется поиск в MainActivity

```
// поиск
searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
          return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
        mAdapter.filter(text);
        return false;
     }
});
```

Но как добавить в это поле кнопку для голосового поиска?

Попробовал вставить в виджет

```
android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
```

Но ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 0):

[Полный гайд - Creating a Search Interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog)

В манифесте в вашей активити должно присутствовать следующее

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

Содержимое searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="search..."
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>
```

Так же в содержимое класса вашей активити нужно добавить

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }
}
```

doMySearch(query) - по сути и является onQueryTextSubmit(String text)